# Including map in open graph post [Android]

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

This has really been confusing me. I have a object which inherits from 'Place' and I add geo location, yet when I post I see no map appear. If anyone could link to a tutorial or give me an answer it would be greatly appreciate. Here is my current code for my object, thanks

```
     ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "myapp:log")
            .putString("og:title", "Title")
            .putString("og:description", "Desc")
            .putString("place:location:latitude","1.0")
            .putString("place:location:longitude","1.0")
            .build();
```